# Get a copy of a List using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have an object that contains a list of other objects.  Say it's as follows:

```
class Keychain {
    public List<Object> keys = new ArrayList<Object>();
}

class Key {
    public String name;
}
```

I get an array of all the Fields available for the class (in this case Keychain) and check to see if any are an instance of a List.  If it is, I want to grab a copy of that list and manipulate the data.

```
for(Field f : keychain.getFields()){
    if(f.getType() == List.class){
        List<Object> keys = f.getObject(new ArrayList<Object>);
        // IllegalArgumentException thrown...
    }
}
```

For what I'm doing I don't know what the exact class in the list will be, the only thing I do know is who it's parent class will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you call Field.get(obj), passing in the object from which to obtain the value? In other words,

```
List<Object> keys = f.get(keychain);
```

f is the "keys" Field in your case, so f.get(keychain) is equivalent to keychain.keys.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see a `Field.getObject()` method in the javadoc for [Field](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html).  Was this supposed to be [Field.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)? If so, `f` specifies a field of the `KeyChain` class.  To get the value of the field via `get()`, you must provide the instance whose field value you want to retrieve. You are getting an `IllegalArgumentException` because the argument you provided was not an instance of `Keychain`.